# Dealing with big and varying action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement a simple q-learning algorithm. For each state, I have a function that defines the action space which is discrete. I have realized that the action space varies for each state, some action spaces are as big as 2000 elements of possible actions while others are as small as 10 possible actions. Is this wide variation a bottleneck to training? Is 2000 possible actions in a state too big? Or I just need to ensure the number of iterations are as many as possible to capture the wide action space?